# AngularJS scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to improve this JsFiddle code by adding Angular routes, controllers, services etc.
    http://jsfiddle.net/ProLoser/bp3Qu/light/

The problem I'm facing is with the following lines of code

```
function FormBuilderCtrl(){
var scope = this;
....
```

When I tried to convert the above to to this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uhsarp/MdvQk/1/

```
function FormBuilderCtrl($scope){
...
```

Now everything breaks. I'm trying to understand what var scope=this meant and why passing the scope to the function isn't working.

Also, all the Angular directives are delcared as ng: instead of ng- (Example: ng:switch instead of ng-switch). Are they equivalent? Thanks.

Update:

I have followed the advise from the answers and upgraded the Angular version. I also removed var scope = this and injected the scope directly. 
    http://plnkr.co/edit/Clr2T9V8J0z3oxW2HXur?p=preview

The only problem I now face is that whenever I change the field type from "text" to "radio buttons", I get an error (Line 45 in the script.js in the above plukr page)

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
```

I checked the code but can't seem to be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Yes ng:switch and ng-switch are 2 different ways to use the same directive

Comment: It looks like you're using Angular 0.10.5, jsFiddle supports 1.0.2, 1.0.3 and 1.1.1. I changed from your version of Angular to a newer version and some things were still broken but stuff began to work. I'm going to make an educated guess and say that `var scope = this` was an older Angular method for fetching scope and the new method is to have it passed as a parameter. Which is why your code would be messing up as it would be using an unsupported means for receiving the proper scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your angular version is very old.

Use the last one: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.js

You need, also, include ng-app in your body tag (or in a wrap div).

I can not find anywhere in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/) any reference to ng:tag style. So, I reccomend that you try to use the ng-tag approach.

Last, I strongly reccomend that you read the [developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/overview) to get a better understanding in how you should contruct your app.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a very outdated version of Angular.

I forked your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp3Qu/38/) and updated the version to the latest stable and monkey patched your script:

1. I inject $scope as intended
2. I set scope = $scope so I don't have to replace it all along your code.

I.e:

```
   function FormBuilderCtrl($scope){
     var scope = $scope;
```

Few advices that to ease your development by avoiding spaghetti coding:

- use different files
- create a module and add your controllers / directives to it.

Answer (score 1):

Beteraraba's is right to say that you should probably use a newer version of AngularJS.

That being said, this is not why it breaks.

In your example, `var scope = this` simply makes a variable called "scope" refer to this. So that later in the code you attribute functions to "this". For instance FormBuilderCtrl().editing is going to be set to false because there's a `this.editing = false;` inside that FormBuilderCtrl(). **`var scope = this;` had nothing to do with Angular's $scope!**

If you want to use $scope, you'll need to inject it, but that would change the idea behind that code. If you decide to do that, you can simply do `var scope = $scope` and your code will work, but keep in mind that the functions and attributes defined in your controller will now apply to the $scope and not just the controller!